# Microservice can't reach config service in docker-compose

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, microservices

I currently have two microservices:
- **service** - port 8080, this microservice tries to fetch config from the other microservice.
- **config** - port 8888, this microservice is supposed to provide config.

For some reason my service is unable to fetch configuration from config microservice.
My config microservice should work because I can curl localhost:8888/service/default on my machine I receive:

```
{"name":"service","profiles":["default"],"label":null,"version":null,"state":null,"propertySources":[{"name":"classpath:/shared/service.yml","source":{"server.port":8080,"spring.security.user.password":"admin"}},{"name":"classpath:/shared/service.yaml","source":{"server.port":8080,"spring.security.user.password":"admin"}}]}
```

Error received  [(full)](https://pastebin.com/s3qEkJxh)

```
service | 2019-06-06 21:31:06.721  INFO 1 --- [main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://config:8888   
service | 2019-06-06 21:31:06.894  INFO 1 --- [main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://config:8888. Will be trying the next url if available   
service | 2019-06-06 21:31:06.904 ERROR 1 --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

Docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  config:
    container_name: config
    build: ./config
    ports:
      - 8888:8888

  service:
    container_name: service
    build: ./service
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - config
```

Service Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD target/service.jar /app.jar
CMD [ "java", "-Xmx200m", "-jar", "/app.jar" ]
EXPOSE 8080
```

Service bootstrap.yaml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: service
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://config:8888
      fail-fast: true
```

service.yaml (has service configuration)

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  security:
    user:
      password: admin # doesnt set since no connection
```

Config Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD target/config.jar /app.jar
CMD [ "java", "-Xmx200m", "-jar", "/app.jar" ]
EXPOSE 8888
```

Config application.yaml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config
  profiles:
    active: composite
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        composite:
          - type: native
            search-locations: classpath:/shared

server:
  port: 8888
```

shared/service.yaml (has service configuration)

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  security:
    user:
      password: admin # doesnt set since no connection
```

Any ideas?

I found some similar issues, although they only had issues with their URI, mine is set correctly. 
[Microservice can not reach to Config Server on Docker Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52228734/microservice-can-not-reach-to-config-server-on-docker-compose)
[Docker - SpringConfig - Connection refused to ConfigServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43005558/docker-springconfig-connection-refused-to-configserver)

Comment: Your 2 microservices seem to have a strong dependency between them, what is the rationale behind that?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I intend to create more services, which the config service will provide configuration for.

Comment: I mean that microservices should be independent, and if there are dependencies, it should be resolved in another layer

Comment: You provide a valid point. I guess I didn't really think about that too much.

Comment: There may be an initial delay in config service coming up and by that time the dependent service already trying to connect to it. You can debug it by
After the containers are up ssh into the service container and ping the config container and curl the endpoint too if possible.If this works then it is a timing issue. If not then it is a configuration issue.
You could possible create an environment variable in compose file and set the value to config service and use it to connect to config service.

Comment: Try adding a reconnect logic after few seconds for connection error as the point made by @asolanki is right, I faced something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one service depends on another you have to make sure that the latter is fully started before connecting to it.

In your case, most probably, `config` is started but not ready (context started) at the time `service` is run. As @Ganesh Karewad and @asolanki pointed out, a solution is to implement a reconnection logic. Another solution is to make sure `config` is initialized and accepting connections before you run `service`.

You can achieve that with a script that waits until the `config` app is up. In alternative you could configure the `config` container with a [health check](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#healthcheck) command and after you start it, wait until it is marked as healthy. Then you can run the service container.

Similar issue discussed [here](https://www.marksayson.com/blog/wait-until-docker-containers-initialized/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54210258/8482479)

Hope that helps.